# Best way to localize fonts in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization

How can I localize fonts like localization of text?
Currently I'm using [Wpf Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) for localizing texts and images and it works fine but
I want for each culture a differnet font?

Comment: What do you mean by "localize fonts?"  Do you mean you have separate fonts for each character set rather than one universal font?  How are you doing your text localization?

Comment: I want to have an specefic font for each culture, for text localization I'm using [Wpf Localization etensions](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why does each culture need a different font...?

Comment: Consider languages like English And Arabic the font for arabic should be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to create your own custom composite font.  The FontFamily documention describes how in the CompositeFonts section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.aspx