# How to use a custom CompositeFont in your application?

Tags: wpf, fonts

We have a requirement to use specific fonts for specific foreign languages.  Based on the answer to this question, it seems like CompositeFont would be the best way to handle this.

[Best way to localize fonts in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401923/best-way-to-localize-fonts-in-wpf)

But I'm struggling to get the damn thing working.

I've created a Font.CompositeFont file as follows

```
<FontFamily xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/composite-font"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Baseline="0.9"
        LineSpacing="1.2">

<!-- Name mapping -->
<FontFamily.FamilyNames>
    <System:String Key="en-US">MyFont</System:String>
</FontFamily.FamilyNames>

<!-- Faces to report in font chooser UI -->
<FontFamily.FamilyTypefaces>
    <FamilyTypeface Weight="Normal"
                    Stretch="Normal"
                    Style="Normal"
                    UnderlinePosition="-0.1"
                    UnderlineThickness="0.05"
                    StrikethroughPosition="0.3"
                    StrikethroughThickness="0.05"
                    CapsHeight="0.5"
                    XHeight="0.3" />

    <FamilyTypeface Weight="Bold"
                    Stretch="Normal"
                    Style="Normal"
                    UnderlinePosition="-0.1"
                    UnderlineThickness="0.05"
                    StrikethroughPosition="0.3"
                    StrikethroughThickness="0.05"
                    CapsHeight="0.5"
                    XHeight="0.3" />
</FontFamily.FamilyTypefaces>
<FontFamily.FamilyMaps>

    <FontFamilyMap Unicode="0000-052F, 1D00-1FFF, FB00-FB0F"
                   Target="Comic Sans MS"
                   Scale="1.0" />

</FontFamily.FamilyMaps>

</FontFamily>
```

build property has been set to Resource, and it's been saved with the .CompositeFont filename.

However, setting the FontFamily of any of my fonts to "/#MyFont" doesn't appear to be setting the font.  I'm certain there's a step I've missed somewhere, but I'll be damned if I can find any resources on what that step is. (I'll keep looking however)

Setting the font in a style as follows

```
<Style x:Key="defaultLabelFont"
       TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="#MyFont" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction to what I've missed it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Starting to get the feeling you can only include .ttf in your application this way, and not composite fonts.

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Nope, gave up in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest handling `InputLanguageChanged` event

```
System.Windows.Input.InputLanguageManager.Current.InputLanguageChanged += 
      Current_InputLanguageChanged;
```

and deciding about the font family or size or etc.

```
    private void Current_InputLanguageChanged(object sender, InputLanguageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewLanguage.EnglishName == "...")
            Application.Current.MainWindow.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, and thanks for the suggestion.  I had considered something like this, but we're using so many different font sizes / colours it just didn't seem economical.  That and we're not worried about the input language, just the output for translations.

CompositeFont really is the perfect answer, just wish there were documentation on how to actually use it properly.